# C ambiguity problem

Tags: c

While coding very simple program for removing blanks, tabs, newlines I came across something I don't actually catch on first; even though **if** condition is true only when tab, space or newline doesn't exist it's still executed with the mentioned for some reason.. here is the code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LGT 100

void rem(char s[])
{
 int i;
 for(i=(strlen(s)-1);i>=0;i--)
  if(s[i]!=' ' || s[i]!='\t' || s[i]!='\n')
   break;
  s[i+1]='\0';

}
int main(void)
{
 char v[LGT]={"sdsfg\t"};

 rem(v);
 printf("%s\n",v);
 getchar();
}
```

Comment: This `!=` and `||` is a standard logic problem.  You should write down several cases on paper and evaluate them slowly and carefully.

Comment: This isn't valid C, and just poor C++. Which is it?

Comment: @GMan: it was supposed to be C, after all...

Comment: H. Schildt taught me with his astounding "C++ From The Ground Up" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that

```
  if(s[i]!=' ' || s[i]!='\t' || s[i]!='\n')
```

Is always true.  If `s[i]` is a space, then the latter two checks are true.  If it's not a space, them the first check is true.

To fix this, change these ors to ands:

```
if(s[i]!=' ' && s[i]!='\t' && s[i]!='\n')
```

Or, even better, use `isspace`:

```
 if(isspace(s[i])
```

Answer (score 9):

`s[i]!=' ' || s[i]!='\t' || s[i]!='\n'` is **always** true. A character can't be equal to both a space, a tab and a newline.

Answer (score 2):

`s[i] != x || s[i] != y` is true for all different values of `x` and `y`.

You probably want `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it, any expression like the following is suspect...

```
a != x || a != y
```

Whatever `a` is, it will always not be one thing OR not be another. So this is always true. The equivalent mistake with `and` is always false rather than always true, and it looks like:

```
a == x && a == y
```

It's a little easier to see, right?  Thing `a` can't possibly be both `x` AND `y` at the same time. And in fact these statements are related by [De Morgan's laws.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeMorgan%27s_Law)

*Update:*  So, typically what you want is `a != x && a != y`. For the second case: `a == x || a == y`.

Comment: How would I properly nest those 3 conditions

Comment: For the first, you want: `a != x && a != y` and for the second: `a == x || a == y`

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
if(s[i]!=' ' || s[i]!='\t' || s[i]!='\n')

break;
```

with

```
 if(s[i]!=' ' && s[i]!='\t' && s[i]!='\n')
   break;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, your boolean expression is a tautology (ie always true). You might also want to use the function `strpbrk()` instead of duplicating functionality provided by the standard library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// …

char text[] = "foo\tbar\n";
char *tail = strpbrk(text, " \t\n");
if(tail) *tail = 0;
printf("<%s>", text); // prints <foo>
```

<del>Also, when including `<c…>` headers, you should prefix identifiers with `std::` or add a `using` directive. Alternatively, use `<….h>` instead.

Using functionality not inherited from the C standard library, more idiomatic C++ code would look like this:</del>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// …

std::string text = "foo\tbar\n";
std::size_t pos = text.find_first_of(" \t\n");
if(pos != std::string::npos)
    text.erase(pos);
std::cout << '<' << text << '>'; // prints <foo>
```

Comment: @highlevelcoder: then you should definitely use `<stdio.h>` instead of `<cstdio>` - the latter shouldn't even compile..

Comment: @highlevelcoder: C and C++ are different languages - C++ is not an updated version of C! however, the C++ standard library inccorporates the C standard library verbatim when possible

Comment: It's true that I'm a beginner but I'm standing with the fact that C++ is just object oriented update of C and it's very much the same with more power and features; stdio.h puts its content into global and cstd into std namespace; H. Schildt in C++ from the ground up at least said that it's ok

Comment: @highlevelcoder: C++ hasn't been 'just an object-oriented update of C' for a long time; in particular, there is quite a lot of legal C code which isn't legal C++; also, the `<c…>` headers make use of C++-only features, so using them in a C program will most likely fail horribly...

Comment: @highlevelcoder: Wrong. Programming in C++ like it's C will only get you into trouble eventually. If you're a beginner in the language, please take the advice of others here and learn the proper idioms for whichever language (C or C++) that you desire to learn.

Comment: @highlevelcoder: As an admitted beginner on what grounds can you possibly assert you know something about the relationship between the languages?